# Private Database cannot query on queryable field

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I maintain a locationId field of type String that is queryable in a CKRecord and when I query on it with valid locationId it gives error: 'An error that is returned when the specified request contains bad information."

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locationId == %@", locationID)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: Cloud.Entity.Infrastructure, predicate: predicate)
    
    self.privateDB?.perform(query, inZoneWith: appDelegate.privateContactZoneID ) { (records, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: ckerror)
            }
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        if let records = records {
            completionHandler(records, nil)
        }
    }
```

I verify in CloudKit Dashboard the Infrastructure record exists with field locationId that is queryable and has correct value I a looking for.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `Cloud.Entity.Infrastructure`?

Comment: String defined as "infrastructure", name of CKRecord

Comment: Why don't you hard-code an actual record type name as a string?

Comment: This probably isn't it, but remove one of the `=` in your `NSPredicate`. You only need one equal sign. What is `locationID`?

Comment: It is = that is correct. locationID is locationCKRecord.RecordID